# Android : change APIRequest to HttpClient

Tags: android

In my APIRequest class

```
if (paramBytes != null)
            {
                if(m_RequestMethod.equals("POST"))
                {
                    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                    out.write(paramBytes, 0, paramBytes.length); // to fix broken pipe
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                }   

            }
```

and

```
case POST:
        {
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

            // add headers
            for (NameValuePair h : headers)
            {
                // request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                request.setHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
            }

            // Add Parameters
            if (params != null && !params.isEmpty())
            {
                request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,
                        HTTP.UTF_8));
            }

            if (entity != null)
            {

                request.setEntity(entity);
            }

            retVal = executeRequest(request, url);

            break;
        }
```

How can I add this code in httpclent
or
how to pass a jsonobject in http client
in API there is a method `setEntity()`
in http is there any method available?

Comment: why don't you use volley? it's kinda official now

Comment: http is deprecated use volley or retrofit etc

Answer (score 0):

create json object then call jsonobj.put(key,value)
create a arraylist of namevaluepair call listobj.put(key, jsonob.tostring())

Comment: i am using eclips, and its a part of maintenance.

Comment: could u pls elobrate ur last answer. I didn't get u.  Do mean u want to increase app performance.?

Comment: no, actually i had already use http client for this app, i can not change whole app request to volley

Comment: bt http client has been deprecated it may be possible that it would probably be  removed in the later versions so its better if u shift your code to volley or retrofiet

Comment: ok let me try, but its a big head ache. to transfer whole app requests.